# Print 2D array in reverse (C++)

Tags: c++

Write a program that reads 12 integers into a 2D integer array with 4 rows and 3 columns. The program then outputs the 2D array in reverse order according to both rows and columns.

Ex: If the input is:

```
5 7 3
6 4 3
5 6 9
5 2 8
```

then the output is:

```
8 2 5 
9 6 5 
3 4 6 
3 7 5
```

For coding simplicity, output a space after every integer, including the last one on each row.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   const int ROWS = 4;
   const int COLS = 3;
   int arr[ROWS][COLS];
   int i, j;
   for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
               cin>>arr[i][j];
         }
   }
   cout << arr[3][2] << " " << arr[3][1] << " " << arr[3][0] << " " << endl;
   cout << arr[2][2] << " " << arr[2][1] << " " << arr[2][0] << " "<< endl;
   cout << arr[1][2] << " " << arr[1][1] << " " << arr[1][0] << " "<< endl;
   cout << arr[0][2] << " " << arr[0][1] << " " << arr[0][0] << " "<< endl;


   return 0;
}
```

I ended up having to hardcode this question because I couldnt find a way to reverse the 2D array with a loop and get it to be outputted in the form of a graph. Is there a way i could reverse the 2D array using for loops and would it be possible to be able to change the amount of rows and columns and still output the corresponding graph of values?

Comment: `for (i = ROWS - 1; i >= 0; i--)` .. _etc_.

Comment: *would it be possible to be able to change the amount of rows and columns and still output the corresponding graph of values?* -- Arrays are fixed in size.  You cannot resize them.  If you have a 2D array that has 4 rows and 3 columns, you're stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse a 2D array using nested for loops, try

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

   const int ROWS = 4;
   const int COLS = 3;

   int arr[ROWS][COLS];
   int i, j;

   // Input the values into the 2D array
   for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
      for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
         cin >> arr[i][j];
      }
   }

   // Reverse the rows and columns of the 2D array
   for(i = ROWS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      for(j = COLS - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
         cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in comments below if you don't know ROWS and COLS size at compile time dynamically allocate the memory for 2D array(arr) in C++ using new operator.

Comment: `int ROWS, COLS;` -- `int arr[ROWS][COLS];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time constant, not runtime variables.  Variable size arrays are accomplished in C++ by using `std::vector`.

Comment: @Cris -- This answer contains syntax that is not valid C++.

Comment: Whats wrong with it? Sorry im a beginner but I made it work with the code provided by the others.

Comment: @Cris [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/4Kj7o8oa1).  This is one reason why I wished that those compilers would by default *not* allow such syntax.  Also, Microsoft Visual C++ totally rejects this code, all because of that syntax.  And for further proof, there is *no* C++ book that shows syntax looking like that.  Why?  Because it isn't C++.  So I would suggest stop learning C++ from poor websites, and use good C++ books.

Comment: Will do this is just what my teacher taught me and what Zybooks the online textbook that we are using tell us too do.

Comment: Get a new teacher.  The teacher doesn't know C++.

Comment: @Cris your original example uses `const int` for the array dimensions assigned constant values (meaning you know the size at compile-time), which is allowed and fine. The difference here is nemesis using non-const `int`s

Comment: Just a nit-pick on the language used in this answer. The program does _not_ "reverse a 2D array". It outputs a 2D array in reverse. These are completely different operations.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    const int ROWS = 4;
    const int COLS = 3;
    int arr[ROWS][COLS];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    // output the reversed array
    for (int i = ROWS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = COLS - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is very little point reading the data into a 2D array for this program. A `std::vector` would do the trick, sized with `ROWS * COLS` values. You then have the benefit of being able to read those dimensions from the user, which addresses the second part of your question.

```
size_t size = ROWS * COLS;

// Read data
std::vector<int> data;
data.reserve(size);
for (int value; std::cin >> value; )
{
    data.push_back(value);
}

// Validate data
if (data.size() != size)
{
    std::cerr << "Unexpected end of input!\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

When outputting, you can use a reverse iterator through the vector, and simply write a newline every `COLS` values.

```
// Output in reverse
int col = 0;
for (auto it = data.rbegin(); it != data.rend(); it++)
{
    std::cout << *it << " ";
    if (++col == COLS)
    {
        std::cout << "\n";
        col = 0;
    }
}
```

You can even easily fix the *"space at the end of the line"* problem by adjusting your output loop as follows:

```
// Output in reverse
int col = 0;
for (auto it = data.rbegin(); it != data.rend(); it++)
{
    std::cout << *it;
    if (++col == COLS)
    {
        std::cout << "\n";
        col = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
}
```